I cannot get the value from the application.yml file, Spring Boot Kotlin Environment
I am trying different attempts to get the value from the yaml file, but no matter what I try, it stays null.
The application.yml file:
demo-control:
  environment: ${ENVIRONMENT:prod}
  managedRegions: ${MANAGED_REGIONS:us-east-1}

Component Class Attempt 1:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component


@Component
class AppProperties(@Value("\${demo-control.managedRegions}") private val managedRegions: String)

Component Class Attempt 2:
    @Component
    class AppProperties {
        @Value("\${demo-control.managedRegions}")
        lateinit var managedRegions: String
    }

Class that I would like to use the value in:
class AwsProvider(
    private val creds: AwsCredentials,
    @Value("\${demo-control.managedRegions}")
    private val managedRegions: String? = null // Attempt1
) : CloudProvider {


Attempt1
@Value("\${demo-control.managedRegions}")
private val managedRegions: String? = null

Attempt2
@Value("\${demo-control.managedRegions}")
lateinit var region:String


Can you show the code where you are actually using the AppProperties component and checking its content?

In AwsProvider you shouldn't initialize the constructor parameter to a default of null, and you should declare it as String instead of String?.

Using the @Value annotation is a straightforward approach to get config values from application.yml, similar to what you have tried above.
I have used the annotation to inject the config value to a Controller in a sample Spring Boot app which works as expected. The relevant code is shared below:
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
...

@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/orders")
class OrdersController {

    @Value("\${demo-control.managedRegions}")
    private lateinit var managedRegions: String

    private final val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

    @GetMapping(produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun getOrders(): List<OrderDto> {
        log.info("demo-control.managedRegions: $managedRegions")
        ...
    }

And here is the log that prints the demo-control.managedRegions config value:

2024-10-31T16:10:00.504+05:30  INFO 1834 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.d.s.api.OrdersController: demo-control.managedRegions: us-east-1


The application.yml file:
demo-control:
  environment: ${ENVIRONMENT:prod}
  managedRegions: ${MANAGED_REGIONS:us-east-1}


The Spring Boot application:
@SpringBootApplication
class SpringDemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpringDemoApplication>(*args)
}

The build.gradle with Spring Boot plugins and dependency:
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring")
}

implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")


Amit, thank you or your reply.. It looks very similar to what i have done right? I dont understand why yours work, but mine doesnt... or am I missing something?

@user18282672 Okay understood, in case you want to browse through the code and figure out the issue, this sample project with the above changes is now available in the following repo, including an example using  @ConfigurationProperties as well:
https://github.com/amitd291/spring-cloud-contract-demo/tree/main/Producer

And here is the Spring Boot official externalized configuration documentation which describes the approaches of fetching the configuration values: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/external-config.html
